# Let's tidy some of the management related tags

Tags: discussion

For example, we have

- [micro-management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micro-management) and [micromanaging](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micromanaging), just two different ways to say the same thing
- [management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management) and [managment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/managment), it's a typo.

What shall we do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The management typo were just 5 questions involved, I edited them all to sport the correct tag, so now the mistyped tag will be cleaned up and no longer be visible.

"Micromanaging" is just 4, I'll do the same.

That will pop the questions to the front page because they were edited, but I think we will survive 9 questions on the front page.

While there are more "moderator" type things one could do (synonyms, bans) I don't think we need this for typos in a single-digit number of questions :)

Once the wrong one's are no longer on questions, they disappear.